# when i use BackgroundImageSpan in android,but at the end of a line,it does not show

Tags: android, html, textview

when i use BackgroundImageSpan in android,but at the end of a line,it does not show,Just like the red underline in the picture，Normally the background image should be displayed：

```
public class BackgroundImageSpan extends ReplacementSpan {
private static final String TAG = "BackgroundImageSpan";
private Drawable mDrawable;
private int mImageId;
private int mTextColor;
private int mWidth = -1;

/**
 * new BackgroundImageSpan use resource id and Drawable
 *
 * @param id       the drawable resource id
 * @param drawable Drawable related to the id
 * @internal
 * @hide
 */
public BackgroundImageSpan(int id, Drawable drawable, int textColor) {
    mImageId = id;
    mDrawable = drawable;
    mTextColor = textColor;
}

public BackgroundImageSpan(int id, Drawable drawable) {
    mImageId = id;
    mDrawable = drawable;
}

/**
 * @hide
 * @internal
 */
public BackgroundImageSpan(Parcel src) {
    mImageId = src.readInt();
}

/**
 * @hide
 * @internal
 */
public void draw(Canvas canvas, int width, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
    if (mDrawable == null) {//if no backgroundImage just don't do any draw
        Log.e(TAG, "mDrawable is null draw()");
        return;
    }
    Drawable drawable = mDrawable;
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(x, top); // translate to the left top point
    mDrawable.setBounds(0, -4, width, bottom - top - 12);
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
}

/**
 * return a special type identifier for this span class
 *
 * @hide
 * @internal
 * @Override
 */
public int getSpanTypeId() {
    return 0;
}

/**
 * describe the kinds of special objects contained in this Parcelable's marshalled representation
 *
 * @hide
 * @internal
 * @Override
 */
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

/**
 * flatten this object in to a Parcel
 *
 * @hide
 * @internal
 * @Override
 */
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(mImageId);
}

/**
 * @hide
 * @internal
 */
public void convertToDrawable(Context context) {
    if (mDrawable == null) {
        mDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(mImageId);
    }
}

/**
 * convert a style text that contain BackgroundImageSpan, Parcek only pass resource id,
 * after Parcel, we need to convert resource id to Drawable.
 *
 * @hide
 * @internal
 */
public static void convert(CharSequence text, Context context) {
    if (!(text instanceof SpannableStringBuilder)) {
        return;
    }
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = (SpannableStringBuilder) text;
    BackgroundImageSpan[] spans = builder.getSpans(0, text.length(), BackgroundImageSpan.class);
    if (spans == null || spans.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
        spans[i].convertToDrawable(context);
    }
}

/**
 * draw the span
 *
 * @hide
 * @internal
 * @Override
 */
public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
    // draw image
    draw(canvas, mWidth, x, top, y, bottom, paint);
    // draw text
    // the paint is already updated
    if (mTextColor != 0) {
        paint.setColor(mTextColor);
    }
    canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);
}

/**
 * get size of the span
 *
 * @hide
 * @internal
 * @Override
 */
public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end,
                   Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
    float size = paint.measureText(text, start, end);
    if (fm != null && paint != null) {
        paint.getFontMetricsInt(fm);
    }
    mWidth = (int) size;
    return mWidth;
}
}
```

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: please help me！！！